# How to set the $location to $location.host

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

so $location.path is www.abc.com/portal and host is www.abc.com
I am trying to set the location as www.abc.com

```
$location.path($location.host);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use **$scope.$apply()** after setting `$location.path()` inorder to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to redirect to main route. So try **$location.path("/")**;
it add string after your $location.host();

For example:

```
// suppose $location.host = 'www.abc.com'
$location.path('/example')
// redirect to 'www.abc.com/#/example'
$location.path('/')
// redirect to your "otherwise" [route][1] if '/' isn't define 'www.abc.com/#/'
```

See documentation here:

> [path([path])](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path);
>
> This method is getter / setter.
>
> Return path of current URL when called without any parameter.
>
> Change path when called with parameter and return $location.
>
> **Note: Path should always begin with forward slash (/), this method
>   will add the forward slash if it is missing**.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to change the entire url means from www.abc.com/portal to www.abc.com

It works with

`$location.href =  location.origin;`

Because location.host only contains

> www.abc.com

and that was going to concatinate with

> www.abc.com/portal/www.abc.com

using location.origin I was getting

> https:// www.abc.com

so It is redirecting now.